# php function call parameters not passing

Tags: php

I'm trying to pass a bunch of variables in php to a function when a button is pressed. The button triggers the function fine but some of the variables have incorrect values.

```
        <?php
          function Commit($TID,$total,$itemCount,$barcoded,$barcodedQTY,$nonBarcoded,$nonBarcodedQTY)
          {
            var_dump($TID); //int 2 - correct
            var_dump($total); //string '0.00' (length=4) - incorrect
            var_dump($itemCount); //int 1 -incorrect value
            var_dump($barcoded); // array (empty) // incorrect
            var_dump($barcodedQTY); // array (empty) // incorrect
            var_dump($nonBarcoded); // array (empty) // incorrect
            var_dump($nonBarcodedQTY); //null - incorrect

          }
          var_dump($TID); // int 2
          var_dump($total); // string "87.80
          var_dump($itemCount);// int 3
          var_dump($barcoded); // array (size=1) 0 => string '1' (length=1)
          var_dump($barcodedQTY); // array (size=1) 0 => int 4
          var_dump($nonBarcoded); // array (size=1) 0 => string '14' (length=2)
          var_dump($nonBarcodedQTY); // array (size=1) 0 => string '4' (length=1)
          if (isset($_REQUEST['commit']))
          {
            if(isset($TID,$total,$itemCount,$barcoded,$barcodedQTY,$nonBarcoded,$nonBarcodedQTY))
            {
              Commit($TID,$total,$itemCount,$barcoded,$barcodedQTY,$nonBarcoded,$nonBarcodedQTY);
            }
            else
            {
              echo 'not all variables were set!';
            }
          }
        ?>

      <div class="row" id="powerwidgets">
        <div class="col-md-12 bootstrap-grid">
            <form>
            <button class="btn btn-success" name="commit" style="float:right;margin-right:5em">Commit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" name="revert" style="float:right;margin-right:14em" onClick="location.href ='index.php'">Cancel</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check your `$_REQUEST` or your inputs

Comment: what do u get in var `$total` and `$barcode` ?

Comment: Before sending dynamic values as parameter test by static values. May be you $_REQUEST value is not set properly..

Comment: the values are from the outer script that this function is running in, i did a vardump on them right before they are passed to make sure they are alll correct, should be 2, 87.50, 3, array (0 => string '1', array (0 => int 4, array (0 => string '14', array (0 => string '4'

Comment: a vardump on $_REQUEST showed : array (size=1)
  'commit' => string '' (length=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call commit with the variables:

```
$TID,$total,$itemCount,$barcoded,$barcodedQTY,$nonBarcoded,$nonBarcodedQTY
```

Chances are you haven't confirmed that they all have values. You need to check that for each one with `isset()` - you can also do this in a ternary operator.

```
// isset check before assigning variables

if (!isset($_REQUEST['TID'], $_REQUEST['total'], ...)) die(); // something wasn't set

$TID = $_REQUEST['TID'];
$total = $_REQUEST['total'];
...


/////////////////////////
/////////////////////////


// ternary operators

$TID = isset($_REQUEST['TID']) ? $_REQUEST['TID'] : "default value"; // don't forget to sanitize!
$total = isset($_REQUEST['total']) ? $_REQUEST['total'] : "another default value"; // don't forget to sanitize!

// if default values are not desired, just set the "default" as ""
// and check if variables != ""
```

Without more code though, this is about as much help as you can get.

Comment: We still don't have the code where you set the variables. That is what my code is doing - setting and checking to make sure they are not blank, and/or setting a default if they are blank.

Comment: i get you, but surely irrelevant of how their set, once their set (confirmed by the vardump) they should still be passed fine, correct? or am i missing something?

Comment: Not necessarily; you may have your warnings suppressed in which case it would look like everything is set when something actually isn't, which is the focus of my answer - use `isset()` to check **each** variable (whether in an if or a ternary). And you're leaving this up to chance. We can't confirm that if we don't see more code.

Comment: Side note: You can pass multiple arguments into `isset()` to check

Comment: Good call, I have amended the answer.

Comment: following your advice i an !isset on the variables and found out their set when the first vardump is called but have become unset by the time commit is set (e.g. the button is pressed), is it possible their being garbage collected? is their something i can do to keep them loaded? (making the variables static didn't help)

Comment: We don't have any html code to see what your "button" is doing to submit. If you're just passing data via get or post, and you set the variable (in the same scope) to have a value of the get or post variable (I used request in my code to cover both since we don't know which it is), then there is no way for garbage collection to occur. Again, make sure the variables are in the correct scope.

Comment: added button code, the variables are created and set just above the function declaration, i attempted to use global variables with similar results

Comment: You have to check `isset()` on the `$_REQUEST` or `$_POST` or `$_GET` values. And you still haven't posted the variable declarations.

Comment: i would but their scattered all over the place in this 300 line php file,heres a pastebin of the page http://pastebin.com/33aBZSpp. the important arrays are at the top

Comment: In that pastebin, $TID is not set. The other variables are NOT coming from form data. Because you're hardcoding those values, whatever is a "wrong value" was hardcoded incorrectly. You need to hook this up to change based on form data or change the hardcoded data.

Comment: i think ill insert what i need into some hidden inputs and have the commit button post that to a new php file with just the commit stuff inside, not ideal but should work. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: It doesn't need to be a new php file. It can be the current one. Just change declarations to account for form data, using my ternary operator code which is in my answer: `$total = isset($_REQUEST['total']) ? $_REQUEST['total'] : "0"; // 0 is harcoded as the default right now so let's stick with that as default`